# how to maintain last inserted id and store in session?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have written a code where I have to maintain the last inserted row id throughout the application without refreshing the page where that page has step by step forms without reloading page. I have written code for that but last second inserted id am getting instead of last inserted id. Here the first insertion is happening through jquery ajax call where a file will be called in ajax in that file Am storing the session variable. My code below:

```
<form class="" id="myFOrm" method="post" id="my_form_id"  >
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $fet['id']; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<input type='text' name=''>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type='text' name=''>
</div>
<a onclick="return submitFunction('1', '2')" >Submit</a>
```

my js code is:

```
function submitFunction(current, next) {
var data = new FormData($('#myFOrm')[0]);/
  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"insert.php",
        data:data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
}
```

insert.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2,col3,col4)
        VALUES ('".$val1."','".$val2."', '".$val3."', '".$val4."')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    $my_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    unset($_SESSION['my_id']);

    $_SESSION['my_id'] = $my_id;
    echo $_SESSION['my_id'];
}
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

My next form where that session value needed is:

```
<form id="myFOrm1" class="form-label-left" method="post" id="my_form_id">
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $fet['id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="my_id" name="my_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['my_id']; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="field1">                                                        
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="field2">                                                         
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="field3">                                                         
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me what was I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: after insert script has run it will be redirected to the next form i.e. last form which I wrote above where the session id needed. my requirement is after user login he is redirected to dashboard page where there are totally 7 steps are there, the insertion done in the step1 the form which I wrote first(above). all the 7 steps will be proceeded without page refresh through ajax calls.

Comment: I will tell you the story. first as I said there are 7 steps totally. for every step there is a database backend table, In the step-1, I insert the data into the table-1 then I will get an auto incre. id from that table I want to store that id   in the session because as my application is based on the step-1 table ID all the further steps will run(our entire application runs). I thought of using sessions for that can u please suggest how to maintain info like that?or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this

```
unset($_SESSION['my_id']);
```

Comment: first, thanks for the quick reply. I tried it but no luck, I am getting before the last inserted id like if last inserted row id is 100 am getting 99 value in the session but after insertion last inserted id showing correctly in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2,col3,col4)
        VALUES ('".$val1."','".$val2."', '".$val3."', '".$val4."')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
} else {
    while ($raw = $conn->mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $object_array[] = static::instantiate($row);
    }
    $_SESSION['my_id'] = $object_array->first()->id;
    echo $_SESSION['my_id'];
}
```

you have to write the instantiate method in order to call it in:

```
private static function instantiate ($record) {
    $object = new static;
    foreach($record as $attribute=>$value) {
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

and obviously, in your table module, you have to provide the list of fields that are 'fillable'

i.e.

```
<?php 
    class User extends DatabaseObject {
        public static $table_name = "users";
        public static $fillable = array('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'email', 'dob');

    }
```

Comment: I tried it the data is getting inserted into table but it is showing nothing. just empty in alert box.

Comment: @prasadchinthala  Modifications added.

Comment: I have a very small app that I created as part of my basic training of PHP.

Comment: I am getting the last inserted id and storing successfully in session $_SESSION['my_id'] as well but after next form opened then if am using that session $_SESSION['my_id'] in a hidden field then last second inserted id it is showing rathar than the last inserted id.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi to connect to DB, the. There's a PHP method you can call: mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn). This one returns the id of the record in scope of the $conn (check PHP.net for details about it).

Comment: If you're using MySQLi to connect to DB, the. There's a PHP method you can call: mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn). This one returns the id of the record in scope of the $conn (check PHP.net for details about it).  And do visit the project link above, check the includes folder as it contains all the action. Hope my responses helped

Comment: thanks for your being continiousely replying with patience. can u plz check my above comments about the requiement under the question? can u plz tell me how to run that project? or which file should I check into?

Comment: Download it to your document root, and access it from the browser (i.e. Local host/vehicle_service/db

Comment: can u plz tell me where to declare this method 'instantiate'? in a class? am getting error as I was declaring that method in a class in the same file i.e. insert.php

Comment: Basically you create two classes (neutral) database.php and databaseObject.php. Within those two you create neutral methods and call it from other modules.  Check the above project files, you'll get all the neutral methods in those two files

Answer (score -3):

You have to first Insert the id to database and then if you want to fetch it then fetch it and after this you insert another id on that place

Comment: I had that script